# Sony Vaio Keyboard light never turns off

Tags: keyboard, sony-vaio, backlight

I formatted my Sony Vaio Vpc F13wfx/bc, and all components has working correctly, except for the keyboard backlight.

The problem is that the keyboard light never turns off.

[image]

I tried to install this it:  [Sony® Notebook Utilities](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCF13WFXBC&upd_id=6052&os_group_id=6)  but neither worked.

I installed the windows 7 ultimate 64bits

Anyone ever had this problem? know of any driver that works, or how I permanently turn off the lights?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to setting up the turn off time in the BIOS?

Comment: I'm working and do not have it here,  but as I recall has no such setting in BIOS.  She has few settings. When I get home, I'll search this setting

Comment: @Sebastián You can post comments asking for clarification once you have 50 reputation. Until now, please make answers more substantial or more affirmative – not just one-liners. If you know where this setting is in the BIOS, please describe how to get there, et cetera. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a Long time search, i found  this solution

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight
```

It's working very well.

I'm using Fedora 18 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`sudo "echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/keyboard/brightness"`

Answer (score 0):

try using vaio control center, it may disable or control it, I lost this and battery charging prevention features after upgrading my laptop to win 10, It seems to me win 8 is best solution for some models of sony vaio

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This is a 6 yr old question about Win 7 and it was solved long ago.  If your problem started with upgrade to Win 10 and didn't involve the solutions in the other answers, I suspect it isn't the same issue.  But it would also be helpful to provide a specific solution rather than just mentioning a tool.